# why eclipse have separate distribution based on hardware architecture

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse is java application and should run on OS that has compatible jvm, eg: Linux distribution of eclipse should work on linux whatever may be the hardware, but still Eclipse has a separate distro based on arch , like ppc, x86 etc.
I tried the eclipse source build and it has parameter for hardware.
Is this because eclipse is built that way? or its jvm limitations

Comment: The original vision of "write once, run anywhere" desktop Java is dead, dead, dead. GUI abstraction turned out to be much trickier than the Unix-fed Sun people thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse uses SWT, which is a GUI that uses platform-native UI facilities.

http://eclipse.org/swt/

Comment: the SWT implementation accesses the native GUI libraries of the operating system using JNI [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit] , The Java Native Interface (JNI) is enables Java code to call by native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform)

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the plugin directories, you'll see lots and lots of dlls, at least under windows. This is for stuff like [SWT](http://eclipse.org/swt/), for the GUI. Also, for the builtin web browser, which is based upon [XULRunner](https://wiki.mozilla.org/XULRunner).